# How to match query parameters in the manifest.json in google chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, query-string, manifest.json

I have to send request to background page from contentscript when a page with any of the following things are opened:
1. https://*.salesforce.com/*
2. https://*.dynamics.com/*
3. Any URL with query parameters etn=account&id=some_Id
4. Any URL with query parameters etn=lead&id=some_Id

I am able to do the first 2 things with the following thing in the manifest.json:

```
` "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://*.salesforce.com/*",
    "https://*.dynamics.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.salesforce.com/*", "https://*.dynamics.com/*"],
      "js": ["src/content-script.js"]
    }`
```

I am unable to check only the query parameters.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [`include_globs` and `exclude_globs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#include_globs). The problem with them is that they are not secure (you *can't* guarantee that you are not injecting in a spoofed page). However, if your content script is just there to tell your background script that the page matches the URL, then you should be using a [`webNavigation` listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation). Which one to use depends on when in the process of the page loading you want to be notified. You can use `tabs.executeScript()` from your listener.

Comment: Thanks Makyen. I tried this by writing matches multiple times and pointing to same content-script.js. I used "*" for matching the URLs.